# ECONNREFUSED - Proxying API requests from React

Tags: reactjs, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I am developing a MERN stack app. I am using the `http-proxy-middleware` package for proxying API requests. At the client side, inside "src" folder, I have a file called setupProxy.js. And the code inside is as follows:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/api/products",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:8000",
    })
  );
};
```

As you can see, I am making a request to "/api/products".

But I am receiving error in the console. The error says:

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/products from
> localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000 (ECONNREFUSED)
> (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Also, the request is being made to "http://localhost:3000/api/products".

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @LoolKovsky Can you please elaborate.

Comment: you didn't post the code on the server-side. neither the one from the frontend where you call the endpoint. It is indicated to post a minimum reproducible example so that we can help you